# What is ./nqt in C programming and how do i change file without changing them in the code

Tags: c

So i trying to input multiple files in the assigned program.
My input file code is as such:

```
int read_File(int *hp, int *d, int *s, char t[])
{
FILE *infile;
infile = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
if (!infile)
{
    return 0;
}
else 
{
    fscanf(infile, "%d", hp);
    fscanf(infile, "%d", d);
    fscanf(infile, "%d", s);
    fscanf(infile, "%s", t);

    fclose(infile);
    return 1;   
}
```

i did

$>gcc assignedProgram.c -o nqt

$>./nqt input1.txt

but if i want to read input2.txt, i have to change from input1.txt to input2.txt in the codes. Is there anyway to bypass that and read input2.txt without changing from input1.txt to input2.txt in the codes

like when i tried ./nqt input1.txt => it's normal
BUT ./nqt input2.txt it's segmentation fault:11

I tried:
to change "input1.txt" in the codes to "nqt" but that was a dumb idea

and BTW: what is ./nqt

Please help me!

Comment: You're passing the name as a command line parameter. You just need to pass that to your function and use it.

Comment: `nqt` is the name of your program, this is how you have named it here: `gcc assignedProgram.c -o nqt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write `main()` as one of the equivalent forms below

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { /*...*/ }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ }
```

so that `argc` and `argv` are set up by your environment to proper values.
For example

```
$ ./nqt input.txt
  ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^ --> 1
  \\\\\-------------> 0
```

Translates in your program to

```
argc == 2
argv[0] ==> pointer to "./nqt"
argv[1] ==> pointer to "input.txt"
argv[2] ==> NULL
```

Comment: PS: the identifiers `argc` and `argv` are **VERY** commonly used but you can use whatever you like. Do yourself a favor, though, and stck with `argc` and `argv`

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `nqt`, it is the name of the program you specified with `-o` flag when compiling: `gcc assignedProgram.c -o nqt`. In order to run the program, you need to use `./` prefix, thus `./nqt` means "run the program called `nqt`".

If you want to pass the name of the file as an argument, you should tell `main` function to accept command line arguments: `int argc` and `char* argv[]` (you can read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/)). Then the name of the file you will pass by running `./nqt <filename>` would be stored in `argv[1]`, which you should pass to `read_File` function as an argument.

Comment: Nitpick: `argv[1]` does not *store* arguments; it is a pointer... `argv[1]` points to arguments